# How do i convert a three-letter amino acids to single letter in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, biopython

I'd like to convert a column of three letter amino acids in excel to one letter and print out the one-letter amino acids to each corresponding row in the excel file. I understand I can use biopython for this.,

What I've Tried:

```
import Bio
from Bio.SeqUtils import seq1
seq1("MetAlaIleValMetGlyArgTrpLysGlyAlaArgTer")
'MAIVMGRWKGAR*'
```

But I want it to be understood that I cannot put a string for python to convert. I need to read a whole column in excel and print a new column with the converted 1-letter sequence. The picture for reference:

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YO9a.png)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: thanks, i'll do that now

Comment: updated with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following script below. You need to extend it for all possible three letter combinations. Hope this is useful for you.

```
# open file 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'file')
df.columns=['three letter code']

codes = []
for i in df['code']:
  if i == 'uuu':
    codes.append('U')
  if i == 'cuu':
    codes.append('C')    
  if i == 'uaa':
    codes.append('A')
print (codes)
df['new_code']= codes
df
```

The output is:

```
        code    new_code
0       uuu     U
1       cuu     C
2       uaa     A
```

Comment: I think this will work. Thanks for the tip.